# iOS: error: accessing unknown 'cornerRadius' component of a property

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm getting the following exception which is driving me crazy:

```
error: accessing unknown 'cornerRadius' component of a property
```

This is the line of code:

```
    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0;
```

I'm following this tutorial from December 2010: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2502/introduction-to-calayers-tutorial

According to the documentation UIImageView is a UIView. It has a CALAyer. CALayer has cornerRadius property. I'm on iOS 4.0.

thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you correctly imported QuartzCore?

```
 #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Comment: @By the way, shouldn't the property of an object being always there ? I don't get why importing a framework suddenly makes new properties available. Is because I'm importing superclasses ?

Comment: Because in this case, the compiler doesn't know about it. In UIView.h, CALayer.h, which contains the `cornerRadius` declaration, is not imported. A little trick called "forward declaration" is used in UIView.h to make the compiler handle the CALayer class in the UIView interface declaration. But the compiler doesn't know anything more than the name of the class at this state.